# Linking from my Actions on Google to a web url

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Dialogflow fulfillment integrated with Google Assistant. Right now whenever using voice with Google Assistant, every time the assistant finishes responding, it tries to catch a user response. This is problematic, because I have a simple response with a rich response that is a BasicCard with a url button link. If the user clicks on the link before the assistant finishes reading out the text response, then the user would be taken back to the Action after clicking on the link when the assistant finishes responding, which is a bad experience. Is there a solution for this?

It seems like the reason it goes back is because the assistant wants to prompt the user for a response. Is it possible to stop the Action from whatever it's doing once the user clicks on the link? Or would it be possible to not prompt the user for a response after the assistant responds?

I'm using node.js and I have tried both `conv.ask` and `conv.add`, but they both automatically catch audio from the user right away after the voice response finishes from the Action.

I am using an iOS device for testing.

Comment: `conv.close` will set the Action to not expect the user to respond.

Comment: conv.close will also end the conversation, I still want the action active when the user closes the browser and comes back to Google Assistant